# Printing first value in array only

Tags: java, arrays, printing

Cannot print all values in array only grabs first value it finds and prints it works fine for min and max just not below avaergae names o sales reps

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RepSales
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[]repName = new String[6];
        double[]salesAmount = new double[6];
        System.out.print("Please Enter The Month Which Sales Are To Be Recorded: ");
        String monthName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Sales Reps Name Followed By Monthly Sales: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < repName.length; i++ ) 
        {
            System.out.print("Sales Rep (Full Name):  "  );
            repName[i] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Monthly Sales:  € "  );
            salesAmount[i] = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }
        Double max = salesAmount[0];
        Double min = salesAmount[0];
        Double valuesBelowAverage = salesAmount[0];
        double sum =0;
        double average =0;
        String maxName = repName[0];
        String minName = repName[0];
        String namesBelowAverage = repName[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < salesAmount.length; i++)
        {
            if (salesAmount[i] > max)
            {
                max = salesAmount[i];
                maxName = repName[i];
            }
            if(salesAmount[i] < min)
            {
                min = salesAmount[i];
                minName = repName[i];
            }
            sum = sum + salesAmount[i];
            average = sum/salesAmount.length;
            if (salesAmount[i] < average)
            {
                namesBelowAverage = repName[i] + ", ";//Only printing first value found
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\f");
        System.out.println("********************* ACME Sales Inc ************************");
        System.out.println("\n********************* Sales Report For " + monthName + " ************************");
        System.out.printf("List Of Sales Reps Below The Monthly Sales Average Of €" + "%.2f%n", average);
        System.out.println(namesBelowAverage);
        System.out.println("\nSales Rep With Highest Monthly Sales Of €" + max + " Was : " + maxName);
        System.out.println("\nSales Rep With Lowest Monthly Sales Of €" + min + " Was : " + minName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited to convert uppercases to lowercases but this is still not a question. Please rephrase.

Comment: i am trying to print out the names of the sales reps below the average sales but it seems to juts print out the first value that is below the average rather than a list of names that are all below the average

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is (use `+=` instead of `=`):

```
namesBelowAverage += repName[i] + ", ";
```

But really, this is not printing an array, but constructing a `String` (you should think about using a `StringBuilder` instead).

Comment: This still just prints the first person below the average sales rather than all of the people below the average. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops - one to generate the average and another to test the salesmen.

```
   String namesBelowAverage = "";
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < salesAmount.length; i++)
    {
        if (salesAmount[i] > max)
        {
            max = salesAmount[i];
            maxName = repName[i];
        }
        if(salesAmount[i] < min)
        {
            min = salesAmount[i];
            minName = repName[i];
        }
        sum = sum + salesAmount[i];
    }
    average = sum/salesAmount.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < salesAmount.length; i++)
    {
        if (salesAmount[i] < average)
        {
            namesBelowAverage += repName[i] + ", ";//Only printing first value found
        }
    }
```

Also added the += noticed by Axel.

**Edit** to move the average calculation out of the second loop.
**Edit** fixed Axel's name

Comment: thanks for your this seems to be running fine but printing out the first value in the array twice.

Comment: Because of your initialisation `String namesBelowAverage = repName[0];`

Comment: I tried initialising it differently but dont understand how to declare it without printing the first value

Comment: `String namesBelowAverage = "";`